# sum of multiple of two binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I'm trying to show this equality. I try to expand it but I have no idea to go on.Thanks in advance for your help.
The equality is

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(2i+1){n-2\choose n-1-i}{n\choose i+1}=2(n-1){2n-3\choose n}+{2(n-1)\choose n}+2{2n-3\choose n-1}$$

I write the left side of equality as below

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(2(i+1)-1){n-2\choose n-1-i}{n\choose i+1}
&=
2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+1){n-2\choose n-1-i}{n\choose i+1}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{n-2\choose n-1-i}{n\choose i+1}=2n\sum{n-2\choose n-1-i}{n-1\choose i}-{2(n-1)\choose n}=2n{2n-3\choose n-1}-{2(n-1)\choose n}
\end{aligned}
$$

I appreciate help me to continue.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A034275

Comment: This probably isn't what you're looking for, but these expressions are [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_hypergeometric_series), and so we can derive identities and closed forms algorithmically. In particular you can [ask wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28%282*j+%2B+1%29+*+binom%28n-2%2C+n-1-j%29+*+binom%28n%2C+j%2B1%29%2C+j%2C+0%2C+n-1%29+%3D%3D+2+*+%28n-1%29+*+binom%282n-3%2Cn%29+%2B+binom%282n-2%2C+n%29+%2B+2+*+binom%282n-3%2C+n-1%29) and it will tell you that the identity holds on $(-1,\infty)$. In particular for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm sure that equality holds but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. Rewrite $2i+1$ as $2(i+1)-1$, and split into two sums.
2. For the left sum, apply $(i+1)\binom{n}{i+1}=n\binom{n-1}{i}$.
3. For both sums, use Vandermonde.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I edit my post by your hints but i didn't get the answer yet. I appreciate if you help me to get the answer. where I made mistake that i didn't get the answer. Thank you

Comment: What you did is what I intended.  Now you can show that the two expressions are equal by writing everything in terms of $\binom{2n-4}{n-1}$.  Alternatively, expand into factorials and combine the fractions.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Let $j=i+1$ you can write your sum as:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n(2j-1)\binom{n-2}{n-j}\binom{n}{j}=2\left[\sum_{j=1}^nj\binom{n-2}{n-j}\binom{n}{j}\right]-\left[\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{n-2}{n-j}\binom{n}{j}\right]$$
You can use the hypergeometrics sums:
$$\sum_{j=\max\{0,d+m-N\}}^{\min\{m,d\}}\binom{d}{j}\binom{N-d}{m-j}=\binom{N}{m},\qquad\sum_{j=\max\{0,d+m-N\}}^{\min\{m,d\}}j\binom{d}{j}\binom{N-d}{m-j}=\binom{N}{m}\frac{md}{N}$$
You can choose $d=n$, $m=n$ and $N=2n-2$ to prove:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{n}{j}\binom{n-2}{n-j}&=\sum_{j=2}^n\binom{n}{j}\binom{n-2}{n-j}+n\binom{n-2}{n-1}=\binom{2n-2}{n}+n\binom{n-2}{n-1}\\
\sum_{j=1}^nj\binom{n}{j}\binom{n-2}{n-j}&=\sum_{j=2}^nj\binom{n}{j}\binom{n-2}{n-j}+n\binom{n-2}{n-1}=\binom{2n-2}{n}\frac{n^2}{2n-2}+n\binom{n-2}{n-1}\
\end{align}
Finally
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n(2j-1)\binom{n-2}{n-j}\binom{n}{j}&=\binom{2n-2}{n}\left[2-\frac{n^2}{2n-2}\right]+n\binom{n-2}{n-1}
\end{align}
It is not what you were looking for :(

Comment: $\binom{n-2}{n-1}=0$